# How can we prove the correctness of the integration property of the Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

I was going through an Electrical Engineering textbook and came across the following proof for one of the properties of the Unilateral Laplace transform.

Integration property of the unilateral Laplace transform:
[Link for the proof from the book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BygLm.png)

In the proof, it is stated that:

$$ e^{-st} \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } t \rightarrow \infty \ \ \ (i)$$

and therefore the term:

$$ -\frac{e^{-st}}{s}\int_{0-}^{t}{f(\tau) \ d\tau} = 0 \mbox{, as } t \rightarrow \infty \ \ \ (ii)$$

But my doubt is: Isn't there a case where the real part of $s$, gets cancelled by the function obtained after the integration of $f(\tau)$?

If that happens then we can't guarantee that (ii) would hold true right - i.e. the LHS in (ii) would not be zero right?

So, isn't the proof that has been provided wrong?

Comment: Could I please know the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've edited your question to use Mathjax formatting; please take a look and make sure it's correct. That was almost certainly one reason for downvotes.

Comment: Thank you. I will ensure to use Mathjax formatting in the future question.

Comment: The first term goes to zero if $f(t)$ grows more slowly than an exponential (one of the requirements for existence of the Laplace Transform)